# Why i can't submit the value of input if it's disabled?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My input type has an attributed `disabled` but whenever i save the value in php it does say " field_name is required" why i can't insert when the input is disabled?

```
<input disabled type="number" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" required onclick="getTotal(1)" onkeyup="getTotal(1)">
```

also how in select?

```
<select class="form-control select_group product" data-row-id="row_<?php echo $x; ?>" id="product_<?php echo $x; ?>" name="product[]" style="width:100%;" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" required>
 <option value=""></option>
  <?php foreach ($products as $k => $v): ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"  <?php if($val['product_id'] == $v['id']) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That’s how `disabled` works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled - consider `readonly`- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Comment: Use `readonly` if you want it to show and submit but not let the user change it

Comment: how about in select box how can i make it read only i tried it but it does let me alter the selection the input in readonly is working though^^

Comment: For the select box, you might consider disabling in, then storing the value you want to submit in a hidden input.

Comment: @mykaf can u illustrate me how in the answer section? ^^

Comment: You could also use a `type='hidden'` input before the disabled input

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the value if you submit disabled input. to solve this use readonly instead

```
<input readonly type="number" name="qty[]" id="qty_1" class="form-control" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" required onclick="getTotal(1)" onkeyup="getTotal(1)">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set attribute to "readonly"

or if you don't want to, try programmatically,

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    qty_1.removeAttribute("required")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<select name="product[]" disabled>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="2" />
```